# Firebase Dynamic Links with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dynamic, firebase-dynamic-links

Can I write Firebase Dynamic Links code in React?

I tried the following but it's not working

```
const dynamicLinkParams = {
     link: link,
     domainUriPrefix: "https://adanima.page.link",
     android: {
         packageName: "com.anima",
         fallbackUrl: webShareLink, // Replace this with your web share link
     },
     ios: {
         bundleId: "com.app.adanima",
         appStoreId: "6462848853",
         fallbackUrl: webShareLink, // Replace this with your web share link
     },
 };

const shortenDynamicLink = await app.dynamicLinks().buildShortLink(dynamicLinkParams, 'SHORT');
```